# Making sql column values start with predefined value

Tags: sql

my question is pretty simple, I have a list of IDs which are all integers and I have been asked to have them start with a predefined value in order to be able to go through them easily, in this case I have to get the IDs to start with the first two digits of the year and then have the ID (example: 21-1234 instead of just 1234, this is how I generate my IDs:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you to add more thanks, specially for which DB you are using, which languages etc

Comment: (I mean, tag. Not thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have IDs like `1-2` because `-` isn't a valid number.
So, you can just add the prefix when you get data.

1. Add new column like `id_prefix`

You have to fill it with the required prefix, in your case `21-`.

2. When you select data, change your request

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(id_prefix, id) as prefixed_id, ...
```

Don't forget to add prefix for existing row.

Comment: the problem is that when we will be in 2022 it will still start as 21-1234, is there any way to add the '21-' through this line you think? id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

Comment: No, because it's only integer. Maybe you can add a new column, and here you set the prefix. And when you get objects, you concatenates both fields

Comment: yeah that's true, I just have a question for the SQL request then. If I add new users will their ID start with 21- or does this only affect the IDs that are already in the id column?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Such as what I suggest is only visual, the ID column will not change and can be applied for everyone, at condition that the prefix column is not empty